# Postgresql - How to calculate cumulative sum based on threshold value

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

This is my sample dataset. `Seq_no` and `value` columns are given, `Cum.sum` and `Bucket` columns we need to find using postgresql.  To Find cumulative sum , i can write `sum(value) over (order by seq_no rows between unbounded preceding and current row)` . But ask is reset `cum.sum` if value reach threshold value. For example Threshold value is 20 and sum of the row 1,2 and 3 values are 23 which is greater than 20 . so we reset the window function. The next threshold value calculate from `seq_no` 4 onwards .

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DB fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MCF9lWng)**

The below query recursively calculates both columns `running_sum` and `bucket` but all groups do not exceed 20 in sum. As 20 is a threshold, it makes sense. Or you should play with a threshold to get desirable output.

```
with recursive cte as (
      select seq_no, value as running_sum, 1 as bucket
      from data
      where seq_no = 1
      union all
      select data.seq_no,
             (case when running_sum + value > 20 then value
                   else running_sum + value
              end),
             (case when running_sum + value > 20 then bucket + 1
                   else bucket
              end)
      from cte join
           data
           on data.seq_no = cte.seq_no + 1
     )
select *
from cte;
```

Anyway, you can use this query as starting point.

Comment: Working as expected.. But for small data set is taking more time.. any better approach

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't figure out a way to do it with pure SQL, but here's a plpgsql routine that works:

```
CREATE TABLE public.test(seq_no integer, val numeric);

INSERT INTO public.test(seq_no, val) VALUES (1, 11),(2, 6),(3, 6),(4, 6),(5, 13),(6, 6),(7, 15),(8, 6),(9, 19),(10, 10);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test_cumolative_sum(arg_threshold integer)
RETURNS TABLE (seq_number integer, running_val NUMERIC, cum_sum NUMERIC, bucket integer)
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
DECLARE
    var_table record;
    var_cum_sum NUMERIC;
    var_bucket integer;
BEGIN
    var_cum_sum := 0;
    var_bucket  := 1;
    FOR var_table IN SELECT seq_no, val FROM public.test ORDER BY seq_no LOOP
        var_cum_sum := var_cum_sum + var_table.val;
        RETURN query
        SELECT
            var_table.seq_no,
            var_table.val,
            var_cum_sum,
            var_bucket;
        
        IF var_cum_sum >= arg_threshold THEN
            var_cum_sum := 0;
            var_bucket := var_bucket + 1;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$;

SELECT * FROM public.test_cumolative_sum(20);
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this sql query for calculating the cumulative sum based on threshold value and resetting the sun after reaching the threshold value each time.

```
WITH recursive cte AS (
  SELECT
    seq_no,
    value,
    CASE
      WHEN value > 20 THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END AS reset,
    value AS cum_sum,
    value AS bucket
  FROM your_table
  WHERE seq_no = 1
  
  UNION ALL
  
  SELECT
    t.seq_no,
    t.value,
    CASE
      WHEN cte.cum_sum + t.value > 20 THEN cte.reset + 1
      ELSE cte.reset
    END,
    CASE
      WHEN cte.cum_sum + t.value > 20 THEN t.value
      ELSE cte.cum_sum + t.value
    END,
    cte.reset + 1
  FROM your_table t
  JOIN cte ON t.seq_no = cte.seq_no + 1
)
SELECT seq_no, cum_sum, bucket FROM cte
ORDER BY seq_no;
```

Comment: Cumulative sum and bucket value we need to find. Only seq no and value columns are given

Comment: I tried with generating cumulative sum with mod 20 to find bucket first.. but I am not getting expected result..

Comment: I think first we need to find bucket and cumulative sum